# Java image will not display when imported from source folder

Tags: java, image, classloader

I am a beginner in coding, and I am experimenting with GUI objects.  Using BlueJ, I ran into trouble when using images when I noticed that they would not display when I packed them into a .jar

One of the solutions I read was to put the images in a "src" folder and import the sources in the classes where they're used.  I attempted to use that method here.  I had it working, but I modified some code and now I can't find what's wrong with it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class getResources
{
public static void showPicture(int file)
{
    String stringFile = String.valueOf(file);
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Picture Window");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/" + stringFile + ".png");

    JLabel picture = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/" + stringFile + ".png"));
    JLabel indicate = new JLabel();
    indicate.setText(stringFile);
    panel.add(indicate);
    panel.add(picture);

    window.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    window.pack();
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you are using embedded resources (resources within a Jar or classpath context) then

```
new ImageIcon("/" + stringFile + ".png")
```

Is wrong, as `ImageIcon(String)` expects the named value to be a file and not a resource.

Instead, you should be trying to use something more like

```
new ImageIcon(classLoader.getResource("/" + stringFile + ".png"))
```

Comment: Thank you!  Now it's giving me a NullPointerException.  Maybe it's not reading from the correct directory?

Comment: I'm assuming the `"/" + stringFile + ".png"` is embedded within the Jar file, is this correct?

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  I needed to change that to include the "src" folder.

Comment: Ah dear lord no!  `src` should NEVER be included within the finished Jar.  You should change your packaging process to ensure that this doesn't happen